# Ultimo console errors in Magento 2

Tags: magento, ssh, themes, magento2, console.log

I'm trying to install ultimo on my copy of Magento 2. The theme is appearing in the content configuration panel but it doesn't seem to apply the theme and I'm getting a large number of console errors such as those in the following screenshot:

[image]

This may be because I have been unable to enable the theme properly as I'm having some issues with the SSH.

When I try to enter the following command

```
bin/magento module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow
```

It keeps coming up with messages such as:

```
-bash: bin/magento: No such file or directory
```

I should probably also mention that on this occasion the server where the files are stored is being run by a third party and controlled through a Plesk panel.

If anyone could clarify what it is that I'm doing wrong here I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who posted. It was actually a combination of the answers provided by other contributors plus something from my server provider.

I had to CD into httpdocs (the magento installation folder) and enter the below command

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php  bin/magento module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow
```

Then run 'setup:upgrade', this seems to have fixed the issue and I can now use Ultimo.

Answer (score 1):

verify that you are executing the command from the right location, maybe you did not change the directory to DocRoot where magento is installed:

```
# cd /var/www/vhosts/domain_name/httpdocs/
```

After that execute the command query once again

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed in the wrong folder. That was not the whole problem but it did get me closer to a solution

Answer (score 1):

go to your magento root via `cd` command

then fire below command

```
php bin/magento module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow
```

if still you face issue this may be permission issue then you can reset file/folder permission via below

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed part of the problem and got me closer to a solution.